# How to interpret that "covariance measures linear dependence"?

Tags: statistics

I know the formula of Cov and relevant calculations. But I am not sure that I grasp the following sentence:

> Covariance measures the amount of linear dependence between two random variables. 
>   (From Introductory Econometrics by Wooldridge)

Why can we say it measures linear dependence, rather than non-linear relationship?

Comment: Partial answer: it is possible to have $X$ and $Y$ depend non-linearly on each other, but have covariance $0$. (For example, $X$ being a symmetric random variable, and $Y = X^2$. Then $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = E[X^3] - 0 = 0$.)

Comment: Yes, it's a perfect answer! Many thanks!

Comment: if X is a symmetric RV, then E(X^odd)=0？

Comment: Yes, since $X^n$ for odd $n$ is also symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

Covariance = 0 on the left, 0.9 on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in the class. The professor provided one explanation. He said because the formula is just $X-\mu_X, Y-\mu_Y$, it's not $(X-\mu_X)^2, (Y-\mu_Y)^2.$

Is it the true reason?